# IE10 issue. iFrame not aligned in the center

Tags: iframe, alignment, internet-explorer-10, valign

The iFRame is either getting displayed in the top of the page or at the bottom of the page in IE10.
The same is working properly in IE8. IS there any attribute to be mentioned explicitly in IE10 to align it in the center.

Comment: Please add more information! I don't think anyone can answer your question like this!

Comment: You should post your code (html, css, etc...)